# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятая

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "при  специалисте"  в следующем предложении:

> Комиссия главного антикризисного
> управления в составе: председателя -
> директора управления, двух независимых
> экспертов - Иванова и Петрова при
> специалисте Сидорове решила следующее.

Каким правилом русского языка это можно объяснить?

Comment: @looser, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что придётся оборот с перечислением заключить в скобки, поскольку не видно другого способа обозначить его окончание (тире уже использованы внутри него). А сделать это необходимо, поскольку здесь применена вставка (сказуемое по падежу согласовано с "комиссия"). Перед "при специалисте" знак нужен (если только Иванов с Петровым не "при Сидорове"), и нужно поставить точку с запятой, чтобы исключить Сидорова из перечисления, в котором есть свои запятые (в составе таком-то; при участии такого-то консультанта). В скобках возможны и другие варианты указания состава комисии.

Комиссия главного антикризисного управления (в составе: председателя - директора управления, двух независимых экспертов - Иванова и Петрова; при участии специалиста Сидорова) решила следующее.